# Facebook Like button doesnt show

Tags: facebook-like

Im developing a RPG page and our Like Button has dissapeared.

I used the generator to create the code, and tried the diffrent versions there off non of them works. 
I also used the LINTER and it shows no errors.
I asked my provider and they can find no error.

The page is http://www.wodgotham.com/ and next to the Facebook homepage link above the twitter link the Like button should be.

I have looked through the code and stared myself blind... I dont know what to do

Suggestions and assistance would be highly appriciated

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the code from the generator - you're trying to load

`http://connect.facebook.net/us_US/all.js` - us_US is not a valid locale

The Javascript console on my browser shows the error as a 500 error from that URL, which when clicked says /*  Not a valid locale.  */

Comment: Thanks alot that worked, no clue how that got there. Even tried on a test page earlier with code from generator.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Igy is correct. "en_US" would be the valid locale.